# How telegram app make smooth animation when swipe back?

Tags: swift, animation, transition, navigationcontroller

when telegraphing when swapping backwards, a soft transition still turns out, I will be glad for any help

[video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mePaD.gif)

Comment: i think its custom navigation animation, can u help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

This animation is set by default when you want to navigate to previous ViewController if they are embed in NavigationController. So you can just hold the left side of screen (around 20px at the left edge of the phone) and swipe right.

Comment: yes, but try this in telegram app, in tg animation smooth, better, i think it custom

Comment: @Dima Have you tried something? Maybe reason why your animation is not as smooth as in tg app is that you run your app in simulator.

Comment: @Dima Yes, But you said that animation was better. I supposed you had tried something and it hadn’t been smooth enough so I wrote that one of the reasons could be that you’re running your app in simulator

Comment: can u install telegram on your iphone and swipe back 2-5 times? u understand what I mean) it is also possible in any other application where there is a Navi to do the same swipes ago for comparison

Answer (score 0):

The animation can be either default one(Navigation flow) or custom one(By animating `UIView` instead of `UIViewController` with Navigation flow). But the transition will be smooth only based on the main thread loads that you are handling in your `ViewController`.

For example:

1. If you are doing any heavy operations like core data fetch with
   heavy data, your transition will take some time present your
   controller.
2. If you are using any NSAttributedString with NSHTMLTextDocumentType, it will slow down your ViewController's transition.
3. Especially these operations might be performed in ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear or TableView's delegate/datasource methods.

Comment: my project very simple, no core data, no NSAtrr, and any heavy methods :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class YourViewcontroller: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true


    }


 func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
  }


}
```

Comment: yeah, no effect :(

Comment: yes, like apps on video, but in telegram very smooth swipe